# Multiple volume scatter objects - smoke and fog

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

Hello I have a problem in which my smoke simulation is inside the giant box which has volume scatter and absorption shaders. During rendering the smoke domain is visible as shady object around the chimney as seen in picture.
[image]

I'd like to overcome this problem because I want to make an animation, also I cannot move the fog domain under the smoke, because then there is a visible border - as seen on top of picture.
Thanks in advance!